# How to specify landscape in Android < 9 and sensorLanscape in Android >= 9 in manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, landscape

I have an app that needs landscape orientation.

So I like to use `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` in the manifest.

But for Android < 9 that is not supported, there I need to use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Just putting both in the manifest gives an error.

Is there a way to solve this in the manifest or do I really need to handle this programmatically in each activity `onCreate` using `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it programmatically.  Here's an example:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/0Ej-K4BpaEo

Comment: This is the solution the the OP mentioned in his question.  He asked for an alternative to this.

Comment: @JasonHessley Thanks.  I forgot to to preface with "Yes you need to do it programmatically".